# Why do we take the Expected value of a response variable (y) for an explanatory variable (x) instead of just a single point value of y?

Tags: regression, expected-value, intuition

I am a beginner in Simple Linear Regression. While studying I found out that we take the expected value of y for a given value of such as x E(y|x). I am not getting the intuition behind this. Why don't we just plug the value of x in the regression equation and take the corresponding y value? Why are we assuming a distribution of y and taking the expectation of that distribution? Does it mean for a single value of x there can be multiple values of y?

I am not getting the essence of it. Could someone please explain? This will be a great help for a beginner like me.

Comment: Think about regressing weight on height. Are two people with the same height ($x$) always going to have the same weight ($y$)? Of course not. But it does make sense to talk about the *expected* weight of somebody with height $x$.

Comment: Okay! Now I get it. So, if my understanding is right then for a unique value of x we should get only one value for y instead of expectation, right?